# Is it a way to put border around a Grafana row?

Tags: javascript, border, grafana

I made a Grafana's dashboard who is created by JavaScript and now I think I should add a border around each row to make reading easier.

That's the actual view:
[image]

but as you can see we can't see easily which row is for which "name".

So what I want to do is something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no border option but you could use row titles and row height to separate the rows visually:

[image]

The option for row options can be found in the row menu on the left hand side. Here are the row options:

[image]

There you can choose the title size and you can set the height to create some space between rows.

Comment: Ok that's a very nice answer ! Thank you so much